# Use foreign key object in form validation in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a class named `Subject` which has `Department` as a foreign key. `ShortNameValidation` is a `ValidationAttribute` which validates `ShortName`'s format (the third character of `ShortName` must be equals to the first character of `Department`'s `SingleKey` property). The validation is used inside a controller which creates a new subject by typing a name, a short name and choosing a department from the predefined drop-down list of departments.

I tried accessing `subject.Department` directly inside `IsValid` method, but it was `null`. The only solution I have at the moment is to fetch the department by reading it manually from the database using the `DepartmentId`.

Is there a more elegant solution to inject `subject.Department` automatically?

Code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Example.Models
{
    public class Subject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(4)]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        [ShortNameValidation]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ShortNameValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private AppContext _appContext = new AppContext();

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Subject subject = validationContext.ObjectInstance as Subject;
            // subject.Department returns null - fetch the department from the database
            Department department = _appContext.Departments.Find(subject.DepartmentId);

            if (subject.ShortName[2] != department.SingleKey[0])
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Invalid short name");
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Example.Models.Subject

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Subject</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShortName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShortName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShortName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "DepartmentId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are populating Department on GET

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
 // example only
 Subject subject = new Subject 
 {
     Id = 1,
     DepartmentId = 1,
     Name = 1,
     Department = new Department() { SingleKey = "Science" }, 
     ShortName = "Science"
 };
 return View(subject);
}
```

Then in your form make sure you have a hidden property for `Department`

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Department.SingleKey) // now this will model bind nicely
```

Now after you post your form inside your `ShortNameValidationAttribute` you will have `Department` populated

```
Subject subject = validationContext.ObjectInstance as Subject;
if(subject.Department != null)
{
   // do validation
}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, the `subject` is just a placeholder for the data inserted in the form? I tried creating the `subject` and adding `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Department.SingleKey)` in the form, but `subject.Department` is still `null`. I have updated the question with the code for the view.

Comment: What is the type of SingleKey?

Comment: A `string` with `[Required]`, `[MinLength(1)]` and `[MaxLength(1)]`

Comment: In your edit above i do not see `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Department.SingleKey)`, was that intentional? Hope you have it in your view

Comment: I copied the older version of the view. I double-checked that I had implemented all the steps you described.

Comment: Not being funny, but it works in my machine, i have attached a pic for this. I am not sure what else could be the issue.

Comment: I believe it works, but I can't manage to make it work on my machine, probably something else makes a problem. Additionally, I find this solution a bit hacky, because it prefills the form with data I potentially don't want. I'll keep the question open. Thanks for the effort! :)